# Accessing backbone objects inside requireJS module from console

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm working on my first large-scale Backbone/RequireJS app, and I have a simple question.

When I have a view open on a page, and I'm in the console, how do I access the properties of my Backbone object (Models, Views, etc).

Traditionally in Backbone, I do this:

```
 var myApp : {
    models: {},
    views: {},
    etc...
}
```

Using require, I don't have a global object like this anymore. What I've done for debugging is just create a new object on window that I can then access from the console. Is there a way to dig into this without having to create new variables on window? (I obviously would remove this global obj before production, just would prefer to save the step & go straight to console).

Cheers.

Comment: The console of which browser?

Comment: firefox? Chrome? Safari? Doesn't matter. I simply want to know if I can access the current state of these objects via the console without having to either set a breakpoint (which only gets me access to the vars in that context, not application-wide), or create a temporary global var.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't found a great solution for this, but here's what I do.

If I just want to access a single module, I type out the whole require spell:

```
> require(['models/foo'], function(foo) { window.foo = foo; });
> foo.something();
```

Sometimes, if I need access to multiple modules, I define a one-liner for helper first

```
> var req = function(module, name) { require([module], function(m) { window[name] = m; });}

> req('models/foo', 'foo');
> req('models/bar', 'bar');
> foo.something(bar);
```

And if I need an already existing instance of something, I just set a breakpoint in the debugger and use the locals, which are available in the console in break mode.

I would definitely be interested in a better way, as well.

Comment: I'm hoping there's a better way, but if nothing comes out I'll mark this as answer. Thanks fencliff!

Comment: @ScottSilvi, yeah, just keep it open for the time being. Like I mentioned above, I'd like to know if there was a better way as well...

Comment: I'm new to backbone and requirejs, but this seems bonkers to me. It works, but is very cumbersome.

Comment: Well, it is pretty bonkers. Thing is, you shouldn't doing this live anyway, so it kind of makes sense that it's not exposed in an easy way. The intent here (for me at least) was to expose these properties for testing/debugging. I switched to AngularJS anyway, and my life was forever changed :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `var m = require('your_module')`?

I should work just fine.